# Vaadin -- backend process to wait for a Vaadin event

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin

This Q is asking for resources/direction rather than a specific answer. we're looking to understand the Vaadin architecture on the following problem.

Our application is event-driven, *event* here being a server-side event. 
When our application hears from another, independent application on the server, it asks the front-end (human) user 
to fill out a form, waits till the user does, and proceeds based on what the user said.

Our backend process, say `processB` is calling a method on a Vaadin layout to do the deeds. that method, say `methodA()` is 
supposed to

1. push the form to front-end
2. wait till the user enters data and hits the "OK" button
3. process&return what the user entered.

(1) is working fine. however, the method is returning before the front-end form is processed. This and some other stuff we observed here suggest that Vaadin is running 
two different threads for `methodA()`. So, when we invoke

```
ourUI.methodA();
```

2 different threads are initiated and running to execute it.

Can this be true?? What is the Vaadin logic on this?
it **isn't** a thread from a previous run of the application still remained on the server-- i checked that carefully

What's the best way to make a process wait for a Vaadin event? is there a way to make an independent thread, i.e., a thread that is outside the control of Vaadin UI, wait for a Vaadin event?

we can make `processB` join `methodA()` so that it'll wait until `methodA()` returns. but I don't think this is the best way. and i don't know how to get hold of a Vaadin thread to `join()` it. furthermore, those (seemingly) 2 `methodA()` threads are spoiling it.

we can keep a token for what `methodA()` returns and make `processB` keep an eye on it, wait till value is written there. still-- there must be a better way.

We'll merge `processB` into Vaadin UI (early days yet in development) so that it'll keep running until the UI is terminated. It no longer will be outside the `ourUI`. How does this simplify things?

Note: we've got only one UI for one session/user-- not allowing multiple tabs by specs, and one backend process on one UI/user

We're using Vaadin 7.7 on Java 1.7 and Tomcat 8

//-------------------------

EDIT:

Our backend process, `processB` is a `Runnable` itself and controls the whole logic. it has to wait for the front-end thread **return and deliver the value**. what i'm looking for is how to trigger this-- **getting the value when front-end event returns.** `processB` won't proceed until it gets this value from the front-end.

Comment: Are you aware of Vaadin’s support for [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html)? I have posted multiple Answers on this topic including full working examples. Rather than directly trying to manipulate threads I suspect you should be using some kind of message queue in conjunction with Vaadin Server Push. And be sure to *not* manipulate the Vaadin UI from another thread.

Comment: @BasilBourque serverpush is what we used in item 1 in the Q. what we need is something like "server pull"-- if there's any. i'm guessing there is. is that in server push as well? haven't yet looked into it in that detail

Comment: Why do you wait while user does data-entry? Just let the OK button on the Vaadin form inform your backend service about there entered data. That OK button can even launch a background thread in an Executor to handle work that may take a long while.

Comment: @BasilBourque .. the online examples there aren't working. am I missing something at my end?

Comment: What examples? The problem seems to be with your combining the display of the Vaadin form with reacting to that form’s completion. Separate the two. A background process stimulates Vaadin via Vaadin Server Push to display data entry widgets with an OK button. Done, no waiting, **the background process has completed its task**. Eventually the user clicks OK, and the Vaadin code updates a database or posts to a message queue or adds to a thread-safe Collection or calls a web service, launching a background thread if necessary to handle this work if it will take a while.

Comment: @BasilBourque go click "on-line example"-s - see what it says. **that** examples.